# OpenIdDict Degraded Mode with ClientCredentials flow

Tags: openiddict

I'm following this blog about allowing OpenIDDict to wrap an alternative authentication provider but return a JWT token from OpenIDDict itself:

https://kevinchalet.com/2020/02/18/creating-an-openid-connect-server-proxy-with-openiddict-3-0-s-degraded-mode/

This is really about intercepting the Authorization Code flow rather than the Client Credentials flow, but it provides a good starting point.

Unfortunately it states that "we don't need to override the HandleTokenRequestContext", which is appropriate for the blog but not (as far as I know) for my use case.

I think I need to implement a custom HandleTokenRequestContext but when I do so, the code runs, no errors but the HTTP response is empty. No token is generated.

How should I properly intercept the Client Credentials flow so that I can call out to another provider to validate the credentials, get a result and include that in the custom claims that I need to add to the JWT?

Code below:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
            {
                // Configure the context to use an in-memory store - probably not needed?
                options.UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(DbContext));

                // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
                options.UseOpenIddict();
            });

            services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                                   .UseDbContext<DbContext>();
                })
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");
                    options
                        //.AllowRefreshTokenFlow()
                        .AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

                    // Register the signing and encryption credentials.
                    // options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                    //              .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

                    //Development only
                    options
                        .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                        .AddEphemeralSigningKey()
                        .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

                    // Register scopes (i.e. the modes we can operate in - there may be a better way to do this (different endpoints?)
                    options.RegisterScopes("normal", "registration");

                    //TODO: Include Quartz for cleaning up old tokens

                    options.UseAspNetCore()
                        .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();

                    options.EnableDegradedMode();   //Activates our custom handlers as the only authentication mechansim, otherwise the workflow attempt to invoke our handler *after* the default ones have already failed
                                                    //the request
                    options.AddEventHandler<ValidateTokenRequestContext>(builder =>
                       builder.UseInlineHandler(context =>
                       {
                           //TODO: Check that the client Id  is known
                           if (!string.Equals(context.ClientId, "client-1", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                           {
                               context.Reject(
                                   error: Errors.InvalidClient,
                                   description: "The specified 'client_id' doesn't match a known Client ID.");
                               return default;
                           }
                           return default;
                       }));

                    options.AddEventHandler<HandleTokenRequestContext>(builder =>
                        builder.UseInlineHandler(context =>
                        {
                            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name, OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role);
                            identity.AddClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject, context.ClientId, OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken, OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);

                            if (context.Request.Scope == "registration")
                            {
                                //TODO: Authenticate against BackOffice system to get it's token so we can add it as a claim
                                identity.AddClaim("backoffice_token", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //TODO: Authenticate against internal authentication database as normal
                            }

                            var cp = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                            cp.SetScopes(context.Request.GetScopes());

                            context.Principal = cp;

                            //This doesn't work either
                            //context.SignIn(context.Principal);

                            //ERROR: When this exits the response is empty
                            return default;
                        }));
                });
            //.AddValidation(options =>
            //{
            //    options.UseLocalServer();
            //    options.UseAspNetCore();
            //});

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHostedService<CredentialLoader>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I got this working with 3 changes:

In the HandleTokenRequestContext:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(TokenValidationParameters.DefaultAuthenticationType);
```

Not sure if this is essential or not. Then remove the

```
context.Principal = cp;
```

but re-add the

```
context.SignIn(context.Principal);
```